# How to map values of an xml attribute to some other values

Tags: xslt, dictionary, attributes, transform

I have a XML file similar to the following:

```
<a>
  <b value="a123" />
  <b value="b234" />
  <b value="c345" />
</a>
```

I need to map the attributes to some other value. For example, I want to replace `a123` with `q999`, `b234` with `z998` and `c345` with `u997`. Is it possible to do such transformation efficiently using XSLT? The mapping itself is generated, so I can convert it into almost any format. For now, let's say it's the following XML file:

```
<map>
  <item from="c345" to="u997" />
  <item from="b234" to="z998" />
  <item from="a123" to="q999" />
</map>
```

Maybe there's a better tool than XSLT to do such transformation? Currently I just `sed` through the file many times. Obviously this solution is horribly inefficient and doesn't scale at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**As easy as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:map>
   <map>
    <item from="c345" to="u997" />
    <item from="b234" to="z998" />
    <item from="a123" to="q999" />
   </map>
 </my:map>

 <xsl:variable name="vMap" select=
  "document('')/*/my:map/*/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "@value[. = document('')/*/my:map/*/*/@from]">
  <xsl:attribute name="value">
   <xsl:value-of select="$vMap[@from = current()]/@to"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<a>
    <b value="a123" />
    <b value="b234" />
    <b value="c345" />
</a>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a>
   <b value="q999"/>
   <b value="z998"/>
   <b value="u997"/>
</a>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Overriding the **[identity template](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** for `value` attributes whos value is equal to a `from` attribute in the map.
2. The map is presented inline in the transformation and accessed using the **[`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document)** function. Alternatively, the filepath to the file containing the map can be passed as external parameter to the transformation and the Map XML document can be accessed using again the **[`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document)** function, passing as argument to it this filepath.